# Clang + OpenMP on Linux uses only 1 CPU core

Tags: clang, openmp

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int64_t N = 10000000000;
    float* data = new float[N];
    int64_t i;

    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] = i*i;

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with g++ then during runtime the code uses 4 cores:

```
g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

If I compile it with clang++3.7 then during runtime  the code uses only 1 core:

```
clang++-3.7 -fopenmp -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

In both cases I have set:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Both compilers have been installed from the Debian Testing repository:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-5
sudo apt-get install clang-3.7
```

So, any ideas why the clang only uses one core? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html):

> OpenMP 3.1 is fully supported, but disabled by default. To enable it, please use the -fopenmp=libomp command line option.

It looks like you missed the `-fopenmp=libomp` in your compilation flags.

Comment: Hello. By using this option I get an error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp`. I also tried to use `-fopenmp=libgomp`. With this flag the code compiles but it still uses 1 CPU core.

Comment: honestly, IDK what's wrong, but I would either try to install clang from sources, or to install the package 'libiomp-dev' and use `-fopenmp=libomp` or `-fopenmp=libiomp5`...

Comment: Turns out libomp is somehow bundled with intel omp library. Furthermore the package is currently undergoing some major transition in the Debian repository. And to make things worse it is currently removed from the Testing repository. (but it exists on the sid). I guess will either have to wait or just use the sid version. :) Thanks for the help my friend!

Comment: could you give us your progress? i am strugelling too

Comment: Just struggled with this for a while, I finally got mine building based on these comments by installing intels omp (`apt-get install libiomp-dev`) and then building with it with `clang++ -fopenmp=libiomp5 /tmp/test.cpp`.  Now hopefully cmake finds it..